# Unable to find the correct namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I want to encrypt my XML file with Symmetric Keys in C#

but, when i am trying to declare this:

```
EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();
```

it's give me error: "The namespace not found". 
but i am unable to find the correct namespace for that. I have already tried with `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` but it doesn't works because it's give `Xml` is not exist in this namaspace.

Can anyone tell me the namespace for `EncryptedXml`?

Thank you..!!!

Comment: a simple google search tell me this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml.aspx

Comment: @DownVoter: why downvote here? because If i add direct reference of -  "System.Security.Cryptography.Xml" it's give me Xml is not exist error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a reference to "System.Security.dll" in your project. 
For this you have to go in your project link and then right click to add reference. Here you have to go at `.NET` tab and find the dll and add it.

```
Project  > add references menu - System.Security.dll.
```

Then you can do `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
  System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml
```